# IOS: property and dealloc

Tags: ios, properties, retain

**I have a stupid problem, in my code I do:**

in .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *currentImage;
```

in.m

```
@syntesyze currentImage;
```

then in my class I use "`self.currentImage`"...

**in dealloc I try to do:**

`[self.currentImage release] or self.currentImage = nil`

but my app crash ever and the problem is that "message sent to deallocated instance", why? I have a retain in .h, what's the problem?

Comment: Please try with only [currentImage release];

Comment: Is `@syntesyze` a typo here, or in your code?

Comment: We do self.currentImage = nil in viewDidUnload method.
Though your code looks fine.. I will advice you to enable NSZombies for memory related issues. It will tell you where is the Object getting deallocated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with

```
self.currentImage = nil;
```

in `viewDidUnload` method.

Answer (score 1):

remove self from self.currentImage.

```
[currentImage release];
currentImage = nil;
```

Comment: I use this image to take image from camera, if I don't use sel.currentImage my app crash and I have this message "-[UIImage retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x253b1470"

Comment: I solve my problem with self.currentImage = nil in viewdidunload